# error 404 on new link in my account

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

I've got a problem, which confuses me.
The situation: I have Magento CE 1.8. I develop on a local vagrant VM. I created a new module. I also created a .phtml-file and all nessesary xml-files. In Usere´s my account, I added a link for the new page. So everything works great on my local vagrant installation. But if I tried it on the live-installation, I got an 404 error. So can anyone point me in a direction to find the error. I did not understand why it is working on the VM but not on live.

So if the page would be schown, this problem would be solved, but there is a second problem too. In my modul I created an sql-installtion script (works fine in VM) but it does not start or work on live. I checked the core_resource table, but there is no entry of my module in the live-database.

I would be thankfull for all hints

EDIT:
This is the section where addLink is used:

```
<customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>recurring_profiles</name></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>reviews</name></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>OAuth Customer Tokens</name></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>billing_agreements</name></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_contact</name><path>customer/account/contacts</path><label>Additional Contacts</label></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
```

Comment: tell me account link !

Comment: Have your links been added to frontend?

Comment: Yes they are. Few Moments ago I solved the problem by myself. There was a case camel mistake between the moduls name, the config.xml and the .php class. Don#t know why, but the vagrant VM works with the msitake. On the live server this causes the error. Thanks for your time and help!